# Bootstrap button/pills stops working if the parent has class "pull-right"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, nav-pills

> Scenario

I am using [flatfy](http://www.andreagalanti.it/flatfy/) bootstrap template to develop a simple website.

> Problem

When I try to add a button/pill as a child of an element having *pull-right* class, the button works fine in desktop orientation(landscape), but when I resize browser window to mobile size(portrait), the button/pill stops working altogether. I tried switching browsers, but the result was same. I tried using radio buttons instead, and that didn't work either.

> Example

You can download flatfy template from [here](https://github.com/andreagalanti/Flatfy-Free-Flat-and-Responsive-HTML5-Template/archive/master.zip) and append

```
<ul class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 nav nav-pills pull-right" id="cardFlipPills">
    <li class="active" id="pill-Front"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Front</a></li>
    <li id="pill-back"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Back</a></li>
</ul>
<p class="btn btn-success">Submit</p>
```

after line **176** of index.html to see it in action

> Source

This is the block of code if some code-ninja can figure out the problem without even looking at the demo

```
<!-- Use it -->
<div id ="useit" class="content-section-a">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right wow fadeInRightBig">
                <img class="img-responsive " src="img/ipad.png" alt="">
                <ul class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 nav nav-pills pull-right" id="cardFlipPills">
                    <li class="active" id="pill-Front"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Front</a></li>
                    <li id="pill-back"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Back</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="btn btn-success">Submit</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeftBig"  data-animation-delay="200">   
                <h3 class="section-heading">Full Responsive</h3>
                <div class="sub-title lead3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit atmet sit dolor greand fdanrh<br> sdfs sit atmet sit dolor greand fdanrh sdfs</div>
                <p class="lead">
                    In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commuta rest gestiret. 
                    Sed virtutem ipsam inchoavit, nihil ampliusuma. Scien tiam pollicentur, 
                    uam non erat mirum sapientiae lorem cupido
                    patria esse cariorem. Quae qui non vident, nihilamane umquam magnum ac cognitione.
                </p>

                 <p><a class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View Details</a> 
                 <a class="btn btn-embossed btn-info" href="#" role="button">Visit Website</a></p>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Thank You :)

> Edit

Edit1:
Added screenshot of mobile version
[image: portrait mode of image in which the buttons/pills stop working]

Comment: can you share screen shot of mobile view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the pull-right class from first col-sm-6 and move first section to second and second section to first place. Hope it will fix your issue.

Formatted Code:

```
<div class="row">


  <div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeftBig animated animated" data-animation-delay="200"  style="visibility: visible;">
    <h3 class="section-heading">Full Responsive</h3>
    <div class="sub-title lead3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit atmet sit dolor greand fdanrh<br> sdfs sit atmet sit dolor greand fdanrh sdfs</div>
    <p class="lead">
      In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commuta rest gestiret. Sed virtutem ipsam inchoavit, nihil ampliusuma. Scien tiam pollicentur, uam non erat mirum sapientiae lorem cupido patria esse cariorem. Quae qui non vident, nihilamane umquam
      magnum ac cognitione.
    </p>

    <p><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">View Details</a>
      <a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-embossed btn-info">Visit Website</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6  wow fadeInRightBig animated animated" style="visibility: visible;">
    <img alt="" src="img/ipad.png" class="img-responsive ">
    <ul class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 nav nav-pills pull-right" id="cardFlipPills">
      <li class="active" id="pill-Front"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Front</a></li>
      <li id="pill-back"><a href="#vCard-viewer">Back</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="btn btn-success">Submit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick :D Thank you very much... Can you explain what does _animated animated_ class do?

Comment: It might be duplicated in template, you can have only one animated class. The animated class helps in animating the section with effects. and please upvote the answer if you find it useful.. Thank you :)